# Deploy Django 1.7 App on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I just upgraded my Django to 1.7c2 and tried to deploy to Heroku when I got this error:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing dependencies with pip
       Downloading/unpacking Django==1.7c2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
         Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==1.7c2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 1.5.2, 1.5.8, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.5, 1.6, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.2, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3, 1.4.1, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6)
       Cleaning up...
       No distributions matching the version for Django==1.7c2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
       Storing debug log for failure in /app/.pip/pip.log

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

Heroku obviously does not support Django 1.7 yet. Now I found [this tutorial](https://github.com/djangochurch/djangochurch-developer/blob/master/docs/deployment/heroku.rst) where they deploy a Django 1.7 app... my question is now whether it is possible to deploy my upgraded app or not? I upgraded mainly because of the built in database migrations (to avoid Heroku+South).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your requirements file, instead of giving the package name, give a link to the github repository directly, with your version tag:

```
git+https://github.com/django/django.git@1.7c2
```

Comment: thank you! i resolved this issue by adding https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.7c2/tarball/ to my requirements instead of Django==1.7c2 (which was generated by pip freeze).

Answer (score 2):

This is irrelevant to Heroku, Django 1.7 is not official yet so to install 1.7 in any system you have to use:

```
pip install https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.7c2/tarball/
```

This is clearly Documented in the Django documentation:
https://www.djangoproject.com/download/

Comment: thank you! that's the way I installed django on my local system, the problem was deploying the app on heroku.